# How can I iterate through two lists and compare the values of each in Python?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following lists:

`x = [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6]`

`y = [0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9]`

I want to write a function that iterates through the list and compares each value in order.

> ```
>  def compare_numbers(prob,thresh):
>  output = []
>  for x, y in zip(prob, thresh):
>    if x >= y:
>     output.append(1)
>    else:
>     output.append(0)
>   return output
> ```

> ```
>   compare_numbers(x,y)
> ```

This gives me Type Error:  `'float' object is not iterable'`

Why is this?

I would expect the output to look like this:
`[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]`

Is there anyway I could write this function such that if the "threshold" value was only one digit it would still work?

My current code to make the latter function is:

> ```
> def compare_numbers(prob, thresh):
>  output = []
>  for n in prob:
>   if n >= thresh:
>    output.append(1)
>   else:
>     output.append(0)
> return output
> ```

> ```
> compare_numbers(x,y)
> ```

Yet this returns the Type Error: `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'` when thresh is a list.

Comment: It works fine for me, what's the full traceback?

Comment: Your first version of `compare_numbers()` works for me when the arguments are two equal-length lists of `floats`.  If it ever produces the `TypeError` you present then that will be because at least one of the function's arguments was a float instead of a list.

Comment: The first function when passing two lists, gets hung up on the "x >= thresh" line. Tells me that >= not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the value n from prob with the entire list thresh. What you need to do is to also iterate over thresh.
Here is a small fix that will allow your code to work:

```py
   def compare_numbers(prob, thresh):
     output = []
     for n in range(len(prob)):
       if prob[n] >= thresh[n]:
         output.append(1)
       else:
         output.append(0)
     return output
```

Comment: That definitely works when there is thresh is a list, big thank you for that, but is there a way that the function can accept if thresh is a single value as well? I would like the function to be flexible in that way.

Comment: @brandooo23 a lot of options for that. One solution is just doing a if type(thresh) == "list" do that if not just use the value. Let me know if I can help any other away!

Answer (score 2):

Psychic debugging:

1. Your first function is passed a `float` for either `prob` or `thresh`, but the code assumes both inputs are `list` (really, any iterable) of numbers.
2. Your second function has the opposite problem, it assumes `thresh` is a single scalar value (e.g. `float`), but you passed it as a `list`.

Seems like confusion on your part; you passed the arguments for the first function to the second and vice-versa. I can't say exactly how it went wrong, because you didn't show enough information about how you called the functions, but the tracebacks make the ultimate problem obvious.

If you want a function that accepts either of:

- A single `float`
- A `list` with some number of floats (that can be extended to match `prob` if it's too short)

for `thresh`, you could do:

```
from itertools import cycle

def compare_numbers(prob,thresh):
    try:
        iter(thresh)  # Check if it's iterable, so we can wrap if it's not
    except TypeError:
        thresh = (thresh,)  # Convert float to one-tuple of float for compatibility later
    output = []
    for x, y in zip(prob, cycle(thresh)):
        if x >= y:
            output.append(1)
        else:
            output.append(0)
    return output
```

The loop itself could also be one-lined to just:

```
return [int(x >= y) for x, y in zip(prob, cycle(thresh)]
```

or:

```
return [1 if x >= y else 0 for x, y in zip(prob, cycle(thresh)]
```

for simplicity and a small performance bump.

Comment: Yes the second function was originally designed to accept threshold as a single value, however I've come to realize that I want it to be able to accept lists (assuming both lists are the same length). Is there a way to achieve the code you mentioned above without importing itertools? I cannot packages outside of numpy or pandas for this one.

Comment: @brandooo23 `itertools` comes from standard libraries.

Comment: @brandooo23: If for some reason built-in Python libraries aren't acceptable (they should be fine, all Python distributions save very weird embedded cases are required to include them, and those weird embedded cases probably don't provide `numpy`/`pandas` anyway), you can cheat a bit *if* you assume an iterable `thresh` is in a sequence (e.g. `list`, `tuple`, etc., no iterators, `set`s, `dict`s, etc.) and that `prob` is a collection (has a length). In that case, you can replace `cycle` with sequence multiplication, adding `thresh *= (len(prob) + len(thresh) - 1) // len(thresh)` before the loop.

Comment: Even if you can't make those type guarantees, if you're cool with shallow copying and know the input won't be infinite, you could do `prob = tuple(prob)`, `thresh = list(thresh)` and then you're guaranteed the code in my last comment will work (bonus: If the caller passed a mutable `thresh`, you won't modify their copy). Either way, that repeats the values in `thresh` enough to be at least as long as `prob`, then `for x, y in zip(prob, thresh)` works fine (`thresh` might be longer than necessary, e.g. for `len(prob) == 7`, `len(thresh) == 2`, the new `thresh` is length 8, but `zip` trims it).

Comment: I feel like an idiot lol. I am bookmarking this page incase I do need to consider mutable "thresh". A lot of good info in here for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work whether `thresh` is a list, tuple or a single value:

```
def compare_numbers(prob,thresh):
    if isinstance(thresh, (list, tuple)):
        return [int(x >= y) for x,y in zip(prob,thresh)]
    else:
        return list(map(lambda x: int(x >= thresh), prob))

print(compare_numbers(x,y))
```

Or:

```
def compare_numbers(prob,thresh):
    return [int(x >= y) for x,y in zip(prob, thresh)] if isinstance(thresh, (list, tuple)) else [int(x >= thresh) for x in prob]
```

Output:

```
# list
x = [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6]
y = [0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9]

[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

# int or float
x = [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6]
y = 0.4

[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: The second code worked as expected though I need to brush up on lambda and a few other methods in here. Thank you!